# customAdapter not working properly with asynchronous image download

Tags: android

Hey guys i am trying to create a custom listview with text and images where images are coming from a url. i am trying to display them asynchronously with my list items. but as i scroll down the list, the image in list items changes and wrong images are displayed in listitems. Below is my code snippet:

**CustomList.java**,
it is implimenting my base adapter

```
public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter {

    //private ArrayList listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;

    public CustomList(Context context,ArrayList<ListItem> listData)
    {

        //Toast.makeText(History.this,"hey",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.e("mysize",String.valueOf(listData.size()));
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_row,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.so = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.SO);
            holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            holder.process = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Process);
            holder.cloth = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Cloth);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListItem data = (ListItem)listData.get(position);

        holder.so.setText(data.getSo());

        if(data.getProcess().equals("0"))
        {
            holder.process.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick);
        }
        else
        holder.process.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
        if(holder.cloth !=null)
        {
            holder.name.setText(data.getName());
            Log.e("urlsss",data.getUrl()+ data.getName());
            new ImageDownload(holder.cloth).execute(data.getUrl());
        }

        return convertView;


    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView so;
        TextView name;
        ImageView process;
        ImageView cloth;
    }


}
```

**ImageDownload.class** for downloading images

```
public class ImageDownload extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public ImageDownload(ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
        return rh.downloadBitmap(params[0]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ListItem.java** that is producing my data for each row in listView

```
public class ListItem {

    private String so,name,process,imgUrl;

    public void setSo(String so)
    {
        this.so = so;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setProcess(String process)
    {
        this.process = process;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url)
    {
        this.imgUrl = url;
    }

    public String getSo()
    {
        return so;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getProcess()
    {
        return process;
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        return imgUrl;    }
}
```

This is my main activity where custom-adapter is called

```
public class History extends AppCompatActivity {

    //url to fetch data from
    public static final String URL_HISTORY = "http://192.168.1.233/vendor/history.php";

    //Json tags
    public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";
    public static final String TAG_SO = "SO";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "CustomerName";
    public static final String TAG_DESC = "ClothDescription";
    public static final String TAG_DATE = "DeliveryDate";
    public static final String TAG_PRODUCT_TYPE = "ProductType";
    public static final String TAG_PRODUCT_DESC = "ProductDescription";
    public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "ImageUrl";
    public static final String TAG_PROCESS = "Process";



   HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<ListItem> detail_list;
    ListView listView;


    //key to put in hashmap
    public static final String VENDOR_NAME = "Username";


    //to store fetched data
    String[] so;
    String[] customerName;
    String[] clothesDesc;
    String[] delivDate;
    String[] prodType;
    String[] prodDesc;
    String[] imgUrl;
    String[] process;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        detail_list = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

        //to get vendorname
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("vendorInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String vendor_name =sharedPref.getString("username", "");
        data.put(VENDOR_NAME, vendor_name);

        fetchHistory();


    }


    public void fetchHistory()
    {
        class FetchHistory extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
        {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(History.this,"Fetching...","Wait",false,false);
            }
            protected String doInBackground(Void...params)
            {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(URL_HISTORY, data);
                return result;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String s)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Log.e("myjson",s);
                showHistory(s);
            }
        }

        FetchHistory fh = new FetchHistory();
        fh.execute();
    }

    public void showHistory(String json)

    {


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            int length = result.length();
            so = new String[length];
            customerName = new String[length];
            clothesDesc = new String[length];
            delivDate = new String[length];
            prodType = new String[length];
            prodDesc = new String[length];
            imgUrl = new String[length];
            process = new String[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);
                so[i] = c.getString(TAG_SO);
                customerName[i] = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                clothesDesc[i] = c.getString(TAG_DESC);
                delivDate[i] = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                prodType[i] = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_TYPE);
                prodDesc[i] = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_DESC);
                imgUrl[i] = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_URL);
                process[i] = c.getString(TAG_PROCESS);

            }
        }
            catch(JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e("myexception",e.toString());
            }


            for(int i =0;i<customerName.length;i++)
            {
                //storing all value in hashmap
                ListItem values = new ListItem();
                values.setSo(so[i]);
                values.setName(customerName[i]);
                values.setUrl(imgUrl[i]);
                Log.e("myurl", imgUrl[i]);
                values.setProcess(process[i]);

                detail_list.add(values);
            }




                Toast.makeText(this,"hey",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("hey", "hey00");


        CustomList customList = new CustomList(this,detail_list);
        listView.setAdapter(customList);
        Toast.makeText(this,"you",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("you", "you00");
    }


}
```

My layout file for each row  is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/SO"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Process"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Cloth"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: y are use using BaseAdapter use ArrayAdapter<Object> please? unless you are doing something really facing dont use BaseAdapter

Comment: Which image downloading you are using can you try Glide or Picasso very light weight and works fine

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake.  Your listView recycles views, so instead of creating views for the 100 items in your listView, it just creates enough to fill up the screen.

As you scroll down, that ImageView that was used for position #1, is now the same ImageView being used for position #11, and #21, and so on...

The fix require tracking what positions are currently being displayed to the user, and only setting images for those positions, and clearing the associated imageview (or cancelling the pending download) when it falls off the screen.

You can figure out when your imageView gets reassigned because it will be called in getView again, and from there you can figure out if it has a pending download you need to cancel.

Consider using one of the existing solutions or just checking out how others have done it for a full example.  https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader